# JavaFX ListView SetCellFactory add margin between imageView and Text

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I'll use a ListView as navigation menu. So I found out how to add an ImageView next to the ListCell title using ListView.setCellFactory. But now I want to have more space between ImageView and title. How can I achieve this?
This is my code:

```
        lvNavigation.setCellFactory(listView -> new ListCell<String>(){
        private ImageView imageView = new ImageView();

        @Override
        public void updateItem(String name, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(name, empty);

            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                Image image = getImageFromStatus(name);
                imageView.setImage(image);
                setText(name);
                setGraphic(imageView);
            }
        }
    });
```

getImageFromStatus(name) returns an Image object.
Thats how it actually looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`graphicTextGapProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#graphicTextGapProperty) :

```
setGraphicTextGap(10.0); // Or any other appropriate value
```